# $-3x(8-x)^2 + (8-x)^3 = 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've been asked to find the critical point of a function, where the first derivative is equal to $-3x(8-x)^2 + (8-x)^3$. In other words, I need to find all $x$ where $-3x(8-x)^2 + (8-x)^3 = 0$.

However, I'm finding this algebra problem unexpectedly difficult. Online calculators have all solved for different values of x, which makes it difficult to confirm my solution. I would appreciate it if someone could give me a solution and/or review my solution below. Please outline your reasoning. If my reasoning is incorrect, please outline why. Thank you.

My solution is as follows.

$-3x(8 - x)^2 + (8 - x)^3 = 0$

$\Rightarrow$ $-3x(8 - x)^2 + (8 - x)^3 = (8 - x)^2\left[(8 - x) -3x\right]$

$\Rightarrow$ $-3x(8 - x)^2 + (8 - x)^3 = (8 - x)^2 (8 - 4x)$

$\therefore$ $x = 8, 2$ Are critical points

Comment: You are correct. And also online : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+-3x%288-x%29^2%2B%288-x%29^3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct: 2 and 8 are the critical points, and your reasoning is clear.